# Unable to use justify-content: space-between to create space between two divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been wrecking my brain for several hours now to get the justify-content: space-between to work between two divs (located within another div). I am using flex, and have tried going through flex-wrap, varying positions, but the space between the two divs is not appearing. (Using BEM, hence the classes everywhere).

```css
.description {
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.two-columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-width: 784px;
}

.two-columns__brief {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #2f80ed;
  min-width: 175px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.two-columns__main-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.two-columns__paragraph {
  line-height: 34px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.two-columns__span-accent {
  line-height: 34px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="description">
  <div class="two-columns">
    <div class="two-columns__brief">Brief</div>
    <div class="two-columns__main-text">
      <p class="two-columns__paragraph">Paragraph 1</p>
      <span class="two-columns__span-accent"><b>Conclusion:</b> span</span>
      <p class="two-columns__paragraph">Paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: There is space between your div, I dont get the problem... add different background on your divs and you will that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong. I needed to add width: 80% to my class = two-columns__main-text, and change the min-width to max-width in two-columns__brief, this way when I added the full text to all

's, the spacing worked out just like I wanted it to.
Thanks to eveyrone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `justify-content: space-between` **does not** create space between html elements. [It distributes items evenly, the first item is flush with the start, the last is flush with the end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content). 
So the spacing between two divs appears only if width of the container is greater than total width of two divs. 
For example, the space is in place in the fullscreen mode. 
[image: wide screenshot]

However, if I remove `min-width` the space disappears. 
[image: narrow screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have added some color to the layout so we know whats what:

**red**: background

**blue with green border**: width of the div where you are trying to put `justify-content:space-between;`

**orange** border: your two divs

[image]

So, you were right in your code, it was fully working but because of your wrong width in the blue element (`.two-columns`) it showed you the wrong result.

You can leave the `min-width` as it is, but if you set the `width: 100%` it will look you this:
[image]

Both of your divs are separated with a space between.

Comment: It does make sense, thank you! I messed around a bit more with the paramaters of the divs, but the width: 80% in description does not impact the spacing between the two divs. (I changed width back to 100%, but ran into the same problem). When I have the full text in the two divs (removed it to make it easier to see the divs) there is space left on the right side of the second div (two-columns__main-text that could be taken up by the div to 'free up' the space between the two divs).

Comment: even if you set width 100% in .two-columns doesn't solve your problem? so you leave the 80% for the description but in .two-columns where you have the minimum width, you add an extra code to make width 100%.

Comment: I added width: 100%; 
but nothing changed.

Comment: a question, you want it to be like this https://codepen.io/qnecro/pen/xxdBbdW , or you want the space-between to be in between Paragraph1 , conclucion and paragraph 2 ?

Comment: The first option. Although, all the modifications that I see is the 'width: 100%', which wasn't able to resolve the issue. (Your help is much appreciated by the way, thank you!)